# gatsby-source-prismic-graphql production build throws an error when querying for a sharp processed image

Tags: gatsby, prismic.io

```
childImageSharp {
  fixed(width: 320, height: 320, cropFocus: ENTROPY) {
    ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
  }
  fluid(maxWidth: 800, quality: 90) {
    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
    presentationWidth
  }
}




1:23:36 AM: error There was an error in your GraphQL query:
1:23:36 AM: Unexpected error value: "failed to process https://images.prismic.io/{MYURL}/9164c1cd-2aed-4955-bbf5-23ea20861ac4_565.jpg?auto=compress,format\nError: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/build/repo/.cache/caches/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql/tmp-ced6c46e221e339dcd73ea911900fbca.jpg'"
```

Seems like the plugin first needs to download the images from prismic, but the query runs before the image is downloaded and it throws the error above when production build is run. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I have the same error. But it firstly appeared like one week ago or so, not before. Weird

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can fix this issue by adding the following code to the top of your `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
var fs = require("fs")
var dir = "./.cache/caches/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql"

exports.onPreBootstrap = () => {
  if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dir)
  }
}
```

Source — https://github.com/birkir/gatsby-source-prismic-graphql/issues/162#issuecomment-600641723

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it by downgrading to 
`"gatsby-source-prismic-graphql": "3.3.1"`

this then threw a `gatsby-browser.js` error, but generated the images

then upgraded to

`"gatsby-source-prismic-graphql": "3.4.1-alpha.0"`

this cleared the previous `gatsby-browser.js` error, so right now it's running fine